# "Driver does not support the 0x4680 PCI ID" on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics, intel, pci

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 with 12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-12900K and Intel UHD Graphics 770. When trying to open VLC and some other snap apps I get the following error message printed twice:

```
Driver does not support the 0x4680 PCI ID.
libGL error: failed to create dri screen
libGL error: failed to load driver: iris
```

and the app fails to load correctly. I have added the kernel parameter `i915.force_probe=4680` and I believe my drivers are up to date.

The output of `glxinfo -B` is

```
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: Intel (0x8086)
    Device: Mesa Intel(R) Graphics (ADL-S GT1) (0x4680)
    Version: 22.1.6
    Accelerated: yes
    Video memory: 64051MB
    Unified memory: yes
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)
    Max core profile version: 4.6
    Max compat profile version: 4.6
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.2
OpenGL vendor string: Intel
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa Intel(R) Graphics (ADL-S GT1)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 22.1.6 - kisak-mesa PPA
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile

OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 22.1.6 - kisak-mesa PPA
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 22.1.6 - kisak-mesa PPA
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
```

and the output of `lscpu` is

```
Architecture:            x86_64
  CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
  Address sizes:         46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
  Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                  24
  On-line CPU(s) list:   0-23
Vendor ID:               GenuineIntel
  Model name:            12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-12900K
    CPU family:          6
    Model:               151
    Thread(s) per core:  2
    Core(s) per socket:  16
    Socket(s):           1
    Stepping:            2
    CPU max MHz:         6700.0000
    CPU min MHz:         800.0000
    BogoMIPS:            6374.40
    Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse 
                         sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xt
                         opology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm
                         2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave av
                         x f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb cat_l2 invpcid_single cdp_l2 ssbd ibrs ibpb st
                         ibp ibrs_enhanced tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2
                          erms invpcid rdt_a rdseed adx smap clflushopt clwb intel_pt sha_ni xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves spl
                         it_lock_detect avx_vnni dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp hwp_pkg_req hfi 
                         umip pku ospke waitpkg gfni vaes vpclmulqdq tme rdpid movdiri movdir64b fsrm md_clear serialize pconfi
                         g arch_lbr ibt flush_l1d arch_capabilities
Virtualization features: 
  Virtualization:        VT-x
Caches (sum of all):     
  L1d:                   640 KiB (16 instances)
  L1i:                   768 KiB (16 instances)
  L2:                    14 MiB (10 instances)
  L3:                    30 MiB (1 instance)
NUMA:                    
  NUMA node(s):          1
  NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-23
Vulnerabilities:         
  Itlb multihit:         Not affected
  L1tf:                  Not affected
  Mds:                   Not affected
  Meltdown:              Not affected
  Spec store bypass:     Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl
  Spectre v1:            Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
  Spectre v2:            Mitigation; Enhanced IBRS, IBPB conditional, RSB filling
  Srbds:                 Not affected
  Tsx async abort:       Not affected
```

Do you have any suggestions for what I should next do to solve these errors and be able to use VLC? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably need a kernel 5.16 or even higher

Comment: Thanks. I should have mentioned that I'm on 5.18 now

Comment: Note that you can get bizarre errors from vlc like `Driver does not support the 0xa720 PCI ID.` when you're trying to play a file from somewhere other than your $HOME directory, because for unfortunate security precautions, the snap version of vlc is disabled from doing so. I have no idea why it is complaining about PCIID 0xa720 just because it doesn't even see the file I want it to play. But later on it does also say `[00007f7b340015d0] filesystem stream error: cannot open file /tmp/whatever.mp4 (No such file or directory)`, so always look for that also.